# Save image with custom name

Tags: html

I have the following image tag on a page:

```
<img src="http://photo.com/img/p806792255-6.jpg" id="will6-1" alt="will6-1" title="will6-1" />
```

When a user does a 'Save Image As' the default name is **p806792255-6.jpg**.

How do I make the default name appear as something else, like **will6-1.jpg**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do can be solved by using **content disposition**.

If so, there are several ways to achieve that based on your existing platform and possibly also your preference of tools and/or skills. I think the exact syntax depends on your platform. Be sure to Google the term yourself and follow the examples that are applicable to your situation.

Here is an example:

```
Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=fname.ext"
```

There is a [Microsoft Knowledgebase article explaining Content Disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519):

MS KB #260519 URL: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519

Answer (score 3):

Use the `download` attribute

```
<a download="filename.ext" href="http://website.com/file.ext">download this file</a>
```

Comment: Thanks so much bro i was expecting it will took my hours but this is very easy way !! :D

Answer (score 0):

Without physically naming the image what you'd like to see, I don't see how you can be suggestive to a user what they should name their image. Maybe use a server-side script to render the image then pass off the "suggested name" in the `Content-Disposition` tag. Even then, it'll probably try to use the name of the rendering page (getimage.php/asp/etc) and append the MIME type for the extension).